# Intellij IDEA: Import existing Play project

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework

Just changed my laptop and started install all required software and setup an environment. I've installed Java, Actiator,... Intellij IDEA 14 Community edition (with Scala plugin).

When I import my Play project I don't see any directory in IDEA (app, conf, test...), only roots file.

Does someone know the reason of this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait until IntelliJ indexes/downloads/etc... everything, it will take a while the first time but after it will appear.

(Happened to me last night).

If when it finish loading it still doesn't appear consider using [sbt-idea](https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea) plugin for sbt.

[image]

Comment: So just import as it is and leave until indexing will be done?

Comment: Yes, that's it, wait for a while

Comment: Hmm

Unfortunately doesn't helped me.
I will try to use previous version of IDEA

Comment: Then you will need to use the sbt idea plugin, intellij idea 13 has not a very good integration with play framework.

Comment: Even after sbt-idea plugin was installed and resolving of all dependencies was completed successfully, folders didn't appear in IDEA =(

Comment: you might need the play 2.0 support plugin. Not sure if it is available for community edition. Alternatively you could generate the intellij project files using the activator.